# How to transform a data from an array with vuejs 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table "persons" with several data. One of these data is `date_of_birth`.

I would like to use this data to display the age of the person with moment.js like this : `moment().diff(birthday, 'years');`.

Only I can not transform this data in my .vue file.

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            persons: [],
            loading: true,
            errored: false
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/persons/list')
            .then(response => {
                this.persons = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                this.errored = true
            })
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You don't appear to be loading Moment.js within your file. Is this included elsewhere in your application?

Comment: @ConnorGurney yes !

Comment: Where is it that you're including that?

Answer (score 0):

npm install moment --save then make sure to import it in the file where this.person object is. Use another .then() to add another field to the person object in the state use moment to diff the persons year born from the axios call and the year it is now. Use Moment to diff. Later you display the value on the age state, this way you still have birthday for something later, and the values from the DB are  the same as the ones on the client.

```
 mounted() {
    axios.get('/persons/list')
        .then(response => {
            this.persons = response.data;
        })
        .then(()=>{
            this.persons.age = moment(this.persons.date_of_birth, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.errored = true
        })
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)
}
```

Comment: You only want to import moment where you use it, not globally